# Unity dash has multiple "settings" after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: icons, unity-dash, 17.04

I just updated from 16.10 to 17.04. The Dash now shows 3 settings icons. Two are labeled "System Settings" but have different icons. The other is labeled "Settings" and has the same icon as one of the other two. These two have the icon I'm used to with 16.10. These both start the same program (well the window looks the same). The new icon starts something I've never seen before (and frankly is ugly as ...) that looks like some kind of combination of other tools.

So my question is - how do I get rid of the extra icons? And why did this happen?